# Accessing Gmail using API key and .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api, .net-5

Trying to access my Gmail inbox using the NuGet package Google.Apis.Gmail.v1. I ***don't*** want to use OAuth. I ***do*** want to use an API key.

So I went and acquired an API key: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_apikeys

And then I went here to find out how to authorize using an API key: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started

And then I ended up with this:

```
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "NAME OF MY APP HERE",
    ApiKey = "MY API KEY HERE"
});

var inboxlistRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("mygmail@gmail.com");

inboxlistRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
inboxlistRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = true;

var emailListResponse = inboxlistRequest.Execute();
```

When the last line executes, I get this:

Google.GoogleApiException : Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
**Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.**

```
at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
  ...
```

Why isn't it working? Is there some limit as to what API keys can access? Where does it say?

Comment: There is no identity associated with your API key other than that of your application. But your application is _not_ mygmail@gmail.com and so cannot access the mailbox. You must use OAuth for what you want to do.

Comment: Year 2022: API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal.

Answer (score 0):

An API key is there to identify your API. It does not grant you access to anything.

You still need credentials of the owner of the post box.